# How to store date in an array in firebase in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of users and i want to store the id of every post that they make under their unique id. When i make a post request it stores the data with a new id in the name field and my data in the value field. I just want it to store the post id for specific user.
Something like this:

```
users{
   <unique-user-id1>: [posts-uid1,posts-uid2,posts-uid3,posts-uid4,],
   <unique-user-id2>: [posts-uid1,posts-uid2,posts-uid3,posts-uid4,]
}
```

Comment: dont get it. Is your displayed structure a single document?

Comment: It seems you seek a relational behavior on your Firestore, it looks like foreign keys, just would like to point that out. In any case, just add a new field to every user which will hold an array containing the posts. Either that or add a subcollection for the posts.